# Implementing Custom TokenBackend for rest_framework_simplejwt

Tags: cryptography, pem, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-4.0

I am migrating our Django code that uses `djangorestframework-jwt` to the latest version of `djangorestframework-simplejwt`(5.2.2) in Django 4.0.8. I am having an issue while trying to verify the token.

The issue is because of the fact that our pem file for retrieving public and private keys is hosted on an Amazon S3 bucket. The framework requires passing `SIGNING_KEY` and `VERIFYING_KEY` statically or using `JWK_URL` for dynamically injecting these keys. Is there a way to provide these keys dynamically without using `JWK_URL`?

The `djangorestframework-jwt` framework used to provide handlers for decoding (`JWT_DECODE_HANDLER`) and encoding (`JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER`) the JWT payload. The `djangorestframework-simplejwt` has built-in functions to decode/encode inside the `TokenBackend` class. I also see that `TOKEN_BACKEND_CLASS` is part of `REMOVED_SETTINGS` in `api_settings`. I am having difficulty trying to write a custom backend by overriding `decode()` and `encode()` functions. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding your serializer in the following fashion.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenVerifySerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import (
    InvalidToken,
    AuthenticationFailed,
    TokenBackendError,
    TokenError
)
class MyTokenVerifySerializer(TokenVerifySerializer):
    """
    Check the veracity of an access token.
    """

    def validate(self, attrs):
        token = attrs['token']
    
        payload = {}
        # Decode Token 
        try:
            payload = jwt_decode_handler(token) # Your Decode handler
        except TokenBackendError:
            raise TokenError(_("Token is invalid or expired"))

        user = self.get_user(payload=payload)

        return {'token': token, 'user': user}

    def get_user(self, payload):
        """
        Attempts to find and return a user using the given validated token.
        """
        from rest_framework_simplejwt.settings import api_settings
        from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
        from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

        try:
            user_id = payload[api_settings.USER_ID_CLAIM]
        except KeyError:
            raise InvalidToken(_("Token contained no recognizable user identification"))

        user_model = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = user_model.objects.get(**{api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD: user_id})
        except self.user_model.DoesNotExist:
            raise AuthenticationFailed(_("User not found"), code="user_not_found")

        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed(_("User is inactive"), code="user_inactive")

        return user
```

Hope this helps! Cheers

Comment: Thanks, mate! This is what I wanted. I added a check_exp() function call after decoding the payload to validate if the token was still valid.